# How do I add a value to a custom field on Trello using google scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, trello

Using google scripts and Trello API, I am having trouble sending a put request to set the options on a pre-defined trello custom field.

This is what the trello API suggests for javascript, however since I'm using google scripts, I'm constrained to use google's "UrlFetchApp" class, how would I do so?

```
var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/customField/{idCustomField}/item?token={yourToken}&key={yourKey}";
var data = {value: { number: "42" }};
fetch(url, { body: JSON.stringify(data), method: 'PUT', headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}})
.then((resp) => resp.json()) //Error would occur here 
.then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)))
.catch((err) => console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)))
```

https://developers.trello.com/reference#customfielditemsid

If I were to attempt to run that example in google scripts I get error:
`Syntax error. (line 135, file "Code")`

So I've attempted to use URLFetchApp:

```
  var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + cardId + "/customField/{customFieldIDHere}/item?token={TokenHere}&key={KeyHere}";
  var data = {value: { "text": "42" }};
  var payload = {"customField" : data};
  var options = {"method" : "put",
                  "payload" : payload};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options); //Error would occur here
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch

But I get this error: 
`"Request failed for https://api.trello.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: Invalid value for custom field type"`

I've also attempted to do var `mData = JSON.stringify(data);` and use mData in the options but still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: Instead of adding this information in a comment, please edit your original post.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Does your above script (Javascript) in your question work fine?

Comment: @Tanaike The example given from the Trello API utilizing the fetch does not work, unfortunately. It would most likely work on any other javascript compiler, but since I'm using google scripts, I'm confined to `UrlFetchApp`

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, above script (Javascript) in your question doesn't work. If my understanding is correct, I think that even if the script is converted to Google Apps Script, it also doesn't work. How about this? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes even after converting to Google Apps script it didn't work, I figured out the problem however and posted it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, that I didn't need `var = {customField" : data}`
Instead, all I needed to do was:

```
var options = {
  "method" : "put",
  "payload" : JSON.stringify(data),
  "contentType": "application/json"
};
```